# Laravel Sanctum login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to create a login with `Laravel 8` and `Sanctum`. I have a `Laravel` application without `Vue.js` / `React` or `Angular` and I need to create tokens for api.

When I create a token, authorization on the `API` works great but doesn't work for the web.

I just need to log in and then create a token that can be used for API and of course let the data be stored in the session or cookies so that he can use the web.

Or can you recommend something to me about how it could be solved?

Comment: Welcome to SO .. for `web` you will need session based auth not token in vue,react or anguar web you can use token based auth

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Answer (score 4):

[Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) is a new powerful package that makes authentication easier for different scenarios:

> Laravel Sanctum provides a featherweight authentication system for SPAs (single page applications), mobile applications, and simple, token based APIs. Sanctum allows each user of your application to generate multiple API tokens for their account. These tokens may be granted abilities / scopes which specify which actions the tokens are allowed to perform.

The following `Controller` allows an user to login and create a `token` via Laravel sanctum:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $request->validate([
         'email' => 'required|email',
         'password' => 'required',
         'device_name' => 'required',
      ]);

      $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

      if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
         return response('Login invalid', 503);
      }

      return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
   }
}
```

We can register a `route` that will be managed by the `Controller` above:

```
// routes/web.php or routes/api.php
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
// Route that needs the user to be logged in
/*
Route
   ::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])
   ->name('dashboard');
      */
});
```

Therefore, the following `POST` request with valid credentials will return a token:

```
curl -d "email=admin&password=123&device_name=test" -X POST https://localhost:8000/login
```

Which we can then use to make the next authenticated `API` calls:

```
curl -i https://localhost:8000/dashboard \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_FROM_PREVIUOS_COMMAND>" \
```