# example code / library to login / access (php / laravel) sanctum interface

Tags: python, php, curl, sanctum

I have got a sanctum interface in php / laravel:

The routes are:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->prefix('v1')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/xxx', [\App\Http\Controllers\XxxController::class, 'index']);
```

IN XXxOntroller.php

```
    public function show(Request $request, $xxxId) {
      if (Auth::user()->xxxs()->where('uuid', $xxxId)) {
        $xxx = Xxx::where('uuid', $xxxId)->with('counters')->firstOrFail();

        return response()->json($xxx);
      }
      $this->unauthorized();
    }
```

I am aware of the [Sanctum documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) but what I need is an example or library (Python) of the client side.
I guess the url is `baseUrl/user` and I need to pass `uuid` and `password` to request a CsrfToken.

If have tried using `curl` following [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491204/laravel-sanctum-login) but just got HTML

I have also tried php code

```
$client_id = "you";
$secret = "token";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://domain.cn/api/user',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($client_id.':'.$secret)
    ],
]);
```

and Python sanctum package

```
from sanctum import HTTPClient
```

but also this does not trigger the interface correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is much simpler than assumed. There is is just a `bearing" token required and no CsrfToken, uuid and password. Using python:

```
import requests

BEARER_TOKEN: Final = "secret"
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
DATA_URL = "https://domain.cn/api/v1/xxx/id"
r = requests.get(DATA_URL,headers=hed)
```